# How to send-back some data from server to browser with fetch API's response body

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

`onclick` function for a HTML5 button is implemented like below, to send some data to server with `fetch` API. But I want to be able to receive data from server's response body. How can I do that:

```
function deleteUser(){
        let confirmation=confirm('Are you sure?')
        if(confirmation){
                const req=new Request('/users/delete',{
                        method:'DELETE',
                        body:JSON.stringify({
                                email:this.getAttribute('data-email'),
                                mySay:'Looks like fetch is awesome'
                        }),
                        headers:new Headers({
                                'Content-Type':'application/json'
                        })
                })
                fetch(req).then(res=>{
                        //How can I receive data by server's response body?
                        console.log(res.body)
                        return res.json()
                }).then(data=>{
                        console.log(data)
                })
        }else{
                return false
        }
}
```

On the server-side code, i.e. NodeJS with ExpressJS, I have the following code:

```
server.delete('/users/delete',(req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.body)
        //Server logs browser request body correctly:
        //{ email: 'bob@smith.io', mySay: 'Looks like fetch is awesome' }

        //How can I send back response body from server to browser?
        //The following method is NOT working:
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            res.body=JSON.stringify({
                msg:'I recieved your request'
            })
            resolve(res)
        })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send response use res.json():

```
res.json({
   key: value,
   key2: value2
})
```